# excel opens all the csv files after conversion, need a way so that it does not open

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that is converting xlsx files to csv format it works perfectly but after converting files it opens all csv files, since I have about 1000 its time consuming to close all the files

```
Sub XlsxToCsv()

Dim MyFileName As String, MyPath As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

MyPath = "C:\xlsFolder\"

MyFileName = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsx")

ChDir "C:\csvfolder\"

Do Until MyFileName = ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Left(MyFileName, InStr(1, MyFileName, ".xlsx") - 1), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    MyFileName = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

what changes should I make so that it don't open these csv files

Comment: Close the workbook after you save it`activeworkbook.close true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close the workbook once you have saved it.

```
Do Until MyFileName = ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Left(MyFileName, InStr(1, MyFileName, ".xlsx") - 1), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    MyFileName = Dir
    activeworkbook.close true
Loop
```

Put that in instead of yours. So it will open it, save it as CSV and then close it.